# What hop should I use to get Fuller's IPA hop taste and aroma?

Tags: hops, aroma, ipa

I'm just a beginner brewer, I have done just 5 batches of all-grain beer, some Hefe-Weizens, APA and an Irish Red Ale.

For my next all-grain beer I would like to make an IPA recipe. But the two best IPAs I have ever tasted is the Fuller's IPA and Brooklyn East IPA, I think this two beers are pretty close in taste, being Brooklyn's slightly strongest in hop taste.

I would like to know what kind of hop I have to use to get Fuller's IPA hop taste and aroma.

Someone have an idea?

Tips for my first IPA are welcome too!

Comment: Ok, delete me then , but if you’re trying to replicate a Fullers ipa please use English hops and not a list of American hops . I won’t be posting on this rubbish site again , please ban me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't aware that Fullers made an IPA.  I couldn't find it at the Fullers website.  Fullers  being a UK based brewery I'd suggest looking into East Kent Goldings hops, and Fuggles hops. Both are UK varieties used in many English style ales.

Comment: Willamette is a good US substitute for either of these.

Comment: Brooklyn's East India Pale Ale is an English-style IPA, so brewchez is right on the money.

Comment: I'm planning to use about 60gr of Fuggle (4.3%aa) 60 min, 40gr of U.S Golding (5.8%aa) 15 min and 30gr of Cascade (5.4%aa) 5 min. In a 20L batch. What do you think?

Comment: You'll find Fuller's IPA half way down this page - http://fullers.co.uk/rte.asp?id=175 They are also doing one at the moment called Bengal Lancer, which is really nice and has that classic Fuller's marmalade thing going on.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://thebeerboy.blogspot.ca/2010/03/fullers-ipa-and-bengal-lancer-facts.html), Fuller's IPA and Bengal Lancer are not the same beer. The author, Zak Avery, claims to have spoken to the head brewer and concluded that the IPA is hopped exclusively with Golding.

> Fuller's IPA is a beer that dates from Reg Drury's tenure as head
>   brewer. It was a fairly traditional take on IPA*, being produced at
>   4.8%abv on cask, and also a version that was brewed specifically for bottling. This brew used only one hop, Goldings.

Bengal Lancer uses Fuggles and Golding for bittering, then dry hopped with Golding and Target.

> Bengal Lancer for cask is brewed with Goldings and Fuggles in the
>   copper, and then dry-hopped with Goldings and Target in the
>   fermentation vessel. An identical version is brewed for bottle, but
>   slightly stronger, and it is chill-filtered and pasteurised before
>   being bottle-conditioned

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by Fuller's IPA you mean Bengal Lancer?

I brewed the following recipe last summer for a just-over-five-UK-gallons batch, based on "Sara Carter Bombay IPA" which is supposed to be a Thornbridge Jaipur clone. See http://www.brew.x10.mx/Recipes.html for the original. I didn't think it tasted much like Jaipur, but was struck by the resemblance to Bengal Lancer. I suspect the Amarillo led to the Fuller's "marmalade" taste.

6kg Maris Otter
200g Vienna Malt
(120g corn sugar for priming)
Mashed at 65 degrees Celsius for an hour.

6g Amarillo, 14g Centennial, 13g Chinook at 75 minutes,
6g Amarillo, 13g Centennial, 7g Chinook at 45 minutes,
32g Amarillo, 43g Centennial, 38g Chinook at flameout, steep for 30 minutes before cooling.

Used 11.5g of Nottingham yeast, not the recommended 22g. I repeated the brew later with 22g and felt the result wasn't quite as good.

I doubt however that these resemble the actual hops used in Bengal Lancer. Good luck if you try it.

Comment: This is similar to some Blind Pig (Russian River Brewery) clone recipes I've seen (and am following in my current batch), except the clones all involve dry hopping rather than steeping.